# The css file does not work on localhost when using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I change the index.php file to index.html, it runs main.css file on local. But when I run it with php, it does not see main.css. Bootstrap sees the css files.

Note:The index.html code works when I run on local. There is no problem with the code.

Edit:The problem is not in PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hi</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">  
</head>
<body>

<a href="/panel.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-danger">Danger</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
.btn-primary{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  background-color: #fed136;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Remove the asterisk from `**btn-primary**`

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a PHP problem. This is happening because Bootstrap is overwriting your main CSS. In fact, using the main CSS, give your button an ID name and change it to the main cass. I think this will work

bootstrap default css  btn-primary

```
<a href="" class="btn-primary class_name" ></a>
```

use css

```
.class_name.btn-primary{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  background-color: #fed136;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: The index.html code works when I run on local. But it does not work on php.

Comment: use link <?php base_url ?>/css/main.css

Answer (score 0):

Please do not overwrite the bootstrap classes,instead use custom class say `.btnDelete`.

```
.btnDelete{
   font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  background-color: #fed136;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And also remove asterisk btn-primary.Bootstrap uses snake case notation for naming classes.why don't you use camelCase notation in order to distinguish between user-defined classes and bootstrap classes.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually not a PHP problem. It is happening because Bootstrap is overwriting your main CSS. To actually use main CSS give your button a `id` name then change it in `main.css`. I think that will work. ;-)

Comment: No, just the opposite :). I did it again using ID